# Can I use a python metaclass to keep track of subclasses in separate files?

Tags: python, django, subclass, metaclass

I am new to the community. In my Django project, I have a module called "social" in which I have several files like facebook.py, and twitter.py, each with classes that are subclasses of "SocialProvider"

Example

```
class Facebook(SocialProvider):
```

Also in my social module is a file called "helper.py" which contains a SocialProviderHelper, which I would like to keep track of all SocialProvider subclasses, and generate different lists, and identifiers for them. For example.. the SocialProviderHelper could "find" Facebook and Twitter and add them to various lists like cool_providers = [] popular_providers = [] old_providers, etc, etc. The goal is to make a universal SocialProviderHelper that other areas of code can import and use... for example.. in a view I may want to get all the "popular_providers" names.. so I would import SocialProviderHelper.. and do something like

```
helper = SocialProviderHelper()
helper.getOldProviders()
```

In my SocialProviderHelper, I have:

```
class SocialProviderHelper(object):
    _providers = SocialProvider.__subclasses__()
```

but
    **subclasses**()
returns an empty list seemingly because the "providers" are defined in other files that haven't been imported, and **subclasses**() only maintains weak references to the class if they are "alive".

Is there any way around this ?

**The end goal is to be able to whip up another subclass of SocialProvider anywhere simply by doing..

```
import SocialProvider
    class NewSocialNetwork(SocialProvider)
```

...and have the SocialProviderHelper know of its existence.**

I have tried to implement "**subclasses**() with a metaclass that keeps a registry of subclasses, but a similar problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with a decorator:

```
from SocialProvider import SocialProvider

@SocialProvider.Register
class NewSocialProvider( SocialProvider ):
    pass
```

I've assumed `SocialProvider` is a superclass written by you.  If so, in your superclass file, the `Register` helper could be defined as a class method:

```
class SocialProvider:

    subclasses = []
    @classmethod
    def Register( cls, subcl ):
        cls.subclasses.append( subcl )
        return subcl
```

If not, then you could still define a function somewhere, to be used as a decorator, but it and the list it appends to would have to be defined somewhere else, separate from the `SocialProvider` class.   You mention the problem of not-yet-imported files.  There's nothing you can do to detect a class that hasn't been defined yet, so you'd have to make sure that the files with the subclass definitions *are* imported (e.g. via statements like `import facebook` etc in the `___init__.py` file of your module).

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but thanks a ton! I'll try this!

Comment: Glad to hear it's useful.  If turns out to solve your problem, you can "accept" it by clicking the tick-mark which is at least as good as an upvote.